# designing database to hold different metadata information

Tags: database-design, database, relational-database

So I am trying to design a database that will allow me to connect one product with multiple categories. This part I have figured. But what I am not able to resolve is the issue of holding different type of product details.

For example, the product could be a book (in which case i would need metadata that refers to that book like isbn, author etc) or it could be a business listing (which has different metadata) ..

How should I tackle that?

Comment: Note: If a database stores information about books, then detailed attributes of a particular book would be "data" rather than "metadata". Metadata would be data about the storage mechanism itself, such as the fact that Book.Title is a non-nullable nvarchar(255).
If, however, the data were stored in a book (like an almanac), then information about the book itself (like ISBN, etc.) would be metadata. :-)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is called  the Observation Pattern.

[image]

Three objects, for the example

```
Book
Title = 'Gone with the Wind' 
Author = 'Margaret Mitchell'
ISBN   = '978-1416548898'

Cat
Name = 'Phoebe'
Color = 'Gray'
TailLength = 9 'inch'

Beer Bottle
Volume = 500 'ml'
Color = 'Green'
```

This is how tables may look like:

```
Entity
EntityID    Name            Description
   1        'Book'            'To read'
   2        'Cat'             'Fury cat' 
   3        'Beer Bottle'     'To ship beer in'
```

.

```
PropertyType
PropertyTypeID   Name        IsTrait         Description
   1            'Height'     'NO'       'For anything that has height' 
   2            'Width'      'NO'       'For anything that has width' 
   3            'Volume'     'NO'       'For things that can have volume'
   4            'Title'      'YES'      'Some stuff has title' 
   5            'Author'     'YES'      'Things can be authored' 
   6            'Color'      'YES'      'Color of things' 
   7            'ISBN'       'YES'      'Books would need this'
   8            'TailLength' 'NO'       'For stuff that has long tails'
   9            'Name'       'YES'      'Name of things'
```

.

```
Property
PropertyID   EntityID  PropertyTypeID      
    1           1              4     -- book, title
    2           1              5     -- book, author
    3           1              7     -- book, isbn
    4           2              9     -- cat, name
    5           2              6     -- cat, color
    6           2              8     -- cat, tail length
    7           3              3     -- beer bottle, volume
    8           3              6     -- beer bottle, color
```

.

```
Measurement
PropertyID     Unit       Value 
    6          'inch'       9          -- cat, tail length
    7          'ml'        500         -- beer bottle, volume
```

.

```
Trait
PropertyID         Value 
    1         'Gone with the Wind'     -- book, title
    2         'Margaret Mitchell'      -- book, author
    3         '978-1416548898'         -- book, isbn
    4         'Phoebe'                 -- cat, name
    5         'Gray'                   -- cat, color
    8         'Green'                  -- beer bottle, color
```

**EDIT:**

Jefferey raised a valid point (see comment), so I'll expand the answer.

The model allows for dynamic (on-fly) creation of any number of entites
with any type of properties without schema changes. Hovewer, this flexibility has a price -- storing and searching is slower and more complex than in a usual table design.

Time for an example, but first, to make things easier, I'll flatten the model into a view.

```
create view vModel as 
select 
      e.EntityId
    , x.Name  as PropertyName
    , m.Value as MeasurementValue
    , m.Unit
    , t.Value as TraitValue
from Entity           as e
join Property         as p on p.EntityID       = p.EntityID
join PropertyType     as x on x.PropertyTypeId = p.PropertyTypeId
left join Measurement as m on m.PropertyId     = p.PropertyId
left join Trait       as t on t.PropertyId     = p.PropertyId
;
```

To use Jefferey's example from the comment

```
with 
q_00 as ( -- all books
    select EntityID
    from vModel
    where PropertyName = 'object type'
      and TraitValue   = 'book' 
),
q_01 as ( -- all US books
    select EntityID
    from vModel as a
    join q_00   as b on b.EntityID = a.EntityID
    where PropertyName = 'publisher country'
      and TraitValue   = 'US' 
),
q_02 as ( -- all US books published in 2008
    select EntityID
    from vModel as a
    join q_01   as b on b.EntityID = a.EntityID
    where PropertyName     = 'year published'
      and MeasurementValue = 2008 
),
q_03 as ( -- all US books published in 2008 not discontinued
    select EntityID
    from vModel as a
    join q_02   as b on b.EntityID = a.EntityID
    where PropertyName = 'is discontinued'
      and TraitValue   = 'no' 
),
q_04 as ( -- all US books published in 2008 not discontinued that cost less than $50
    select EntityID
    from vModel as a
    join q_03   as b on b.EntityID = a.EntityID
    where PropertyName     = 'price'
      and MeasurementValue < 50 
      and MeasurementUnit  = 'USD'
)
select
      EntityID
    , max(case PropertyName when 'title' than TraitValue else null end) as Title
    , max(case PropertyName when 'ISBN'  than TraitValue else null end) as ISBN
from vModel as a
join q_04   as b on b.EntityID = a.EntityID
group by EntityID ;
```

This looks complicated to write, but on a closer inspection you may notice a pattern in CTEs.

Now suppose we have a standard fixed schema design where each object property has its own column.
The query would look something like:

```
select EntityID, Title, ISBN
from vModel
WHERE ObjectType       = 'book'
  and PublisherCountry = 'US'
  and YearPublished    = 2008
  and IsDiscontinued   = 'no'
  and Price            < 50
  and Currency         = 'USD'
;
```

Comment: Thanks this is a very good answer and a lead. Let's add more to this discussion. 

In this sort of design how would one account for fast searching? I would imagine that would require a lot of joins ??

Comment: This is a very bad idea, and it will lead to problems further down the road. Please don't do this.

Comment: For example, try getting all the books from US publishers of academic books published in 2008 that haven't been discontinued and cost less than $50. Good luck! In a properly designed relational database that's a 2-minute task.

Comment: @Jefferey, for that one uses data warehouse. The initial problem was having DB with "flexible" columns (properties) for different kind of objects, and ability to dynamically accomodate this without schema changes.

Comment: @John, this would depend on search -- keep in mind that property here is in rows, not columns. To get a "standard table layout" for an entity, pivoting is needed -- which is slow. Essentially, each column that you would normally palace in the WHERE clause requires a sub-query. The easiest thing to do is to make a model, populate and try it out.

Comment: This technique has pros and cons. The big "pro" is flexibility. The big "con" is that it is complicated to query and it is subject to severe entropy. By the latter I mean that if users can create new properties, you will almost surely get a lot of inconsistent properties and shear junk properties. Even if these are controlled by programmers, you will likely get a lot of junk. I'm not saying never do it, but I'd say it should be a last resort.

Comment: Did you really mean "fury cat", or "furry cat". Well, perhaps you have a cat like that one my ex-girlfriend used to have, that could properly be called a fury cat.

Comment: @Jay :) True, though avalanche of properties can be tamed on the application layer using "did you mean...". If there are only few object types and schema changes are ok, Jefferey's suggestion of Supertype-subtype is much better; but, if there are hundreds or thousands of object-types created on fly...

Comment: @Damir: It also depends on who your users are. If it's 4 people in the marketing department, you have a much better chance to keep things under control that if its 10,000 customers.

Comment: I'm still not a fan of this method, but your responses are an excellent contribution to this discussion. I have changed my down vote to an up vote.

Comment: This is an EAV. A SQL anti-pattern according to Bill Karwin http://www.amazon.co.uk/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557/ref=ntt_at_ep_dpt_1/278-1154409-5580237

Comment: @gbn; yes, it is, have the book here.

Answer (score 24):

I wasn't going to answer, but right now the accepted answer has a very bad idea. A relational database should never be used to store simple attribute-value pairs. That will cause a lot of problems down the road.

The best way to deal with this is to create a separate table for each type.

```
Product
-------
ProductId
Description
Price
(other attributes common to all products)

Book
----
ProductId (foreign key to Product.ProductId)
ISBN
Author
(other attributes related to books)

Electronics
-----------
ProductId (foreign key to Product.ProductId)
BatteriesRequired
etc.
```

Each row of each table should represent a proposition about the real world, and the structure of the tables and their constraints should reflect the realities that are being represented. The closer you can get to this ideal, the cleaner the data will be, and the easier it will be to do reporting and to extend the system in other ways. It will also run more effeciently.

Comment: Indeed, I do like super type-subtype too -- the problem is what happens when the number of sub-type tables goes into thousands? How to handle cases when new types are added on fly? What would would be recommended in such a case? Native XML storage or ...

Comment: @bukzor , @Damir Sudarevic - Indeed, I should have answered that question, and I regret that have not done so. The answer is that the database should be designed to reflect the real-world situation that is known. If new "types" are to be added, then only the things that are consistant across those types can be relationally modeled. Some kind of attribute/value system may be called for, but only for those things that are "soft". Basically, if something can be modified by a user of the system, rather than a programmer, then it must be stored as data rather than as structure.

Comment: Thanks! Based on your feedback, I will store the very-stable metrics as measures, but keep an EAV format as well for unforseen additions. @Damir Have either of you seen prior art for this hybrid-type scheme?

Comment: I have a similar problem where I am creating a warehouse management system and different products have different attributes. With the structure you have described, would it be acceptable to allow the admin user of the site to add new product types?

Comment: I feel more comfortable with this approach. A book should 'extend' a product. In my own implementation I did add a field to Products table: "ProductType", which was an enum set, so that the program can easily find the extended properties.

Comment: This is a good idea... unless you have 100 properties. That's where you do away with relational database concepts and denormalize. Standard practice. Even the most academic of database books will tell you there is a time and place for denormalization. This is one of them.

Answer (score 4):

You could go with the schema-less approach:

Hold the metadata in a TEXT column as a JSON object (or other serialization, but JSON is better for reasons soon explained).

**Advantages to this technique:**

1. Less queries: you get all the information in one query, no need for "in directional" queries (to get meta-meta-data) and joins.
2. You can add/remove any attributes you want at any time, no need to alter table (which is problematic in some databases, e.g Mysql locks the table, and it takes long time with huge tables)
3. Since it's JSON, you don't need extra processing on your backend. Your webpage (I assume it's a web application) just reads the JSON as is from your web service and that's it, you can use the JSON object with javascript however you like.

**Problems:**

1. Potentially wasted space, if you have 100 books with the same author, an author table with all the books having just the author_id is more economical space wise.
2. Need to implement indexes. since your metadata is a JSON object you don't have indexes straight away. But it's fairly easy to implement specific index for the specific metadata you need. e.g you want to index by author, so you create a author_idx table with author_id and item_id, when someone searches for author, you can look up this table and the items themselves.

Depending on the scale, this might be an overkill. on smaller scale joins would work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The product should be typed.  e.g. include type_id in the product table, that points to the categories of products you will support, and lets you know which other tables to query against for the appropriate related attributes.

Answer (score 2):

In this kind of problem, you have three choices:

1. Create a table with "generic" columns. For example, if you sell both books and toasters, it is likely that your toasters don't have an ISBN and a title, but they still have some kind of product identifier and description. So give the fields generic names like "product_id" and "description", and for books the product_id is an ISBN, for toasters its the manufacturer's part number, etc.

This works when the real-world entities are all being processed in the same way, at least for the most part, and so must have, if not the "same" data, at least analagous data. This breaks down when there are real functional differences. Like if for toasters we are calcualting watts = volts * amps, it is likely that there is no corresponding calculation for books. When you start creating a pages_volts fields that contains the page count for books and the voltage for toasters, things have gotten out of control.

2. Use a property/value scheme like Damir suggests. See my comment on his post for the pros and cons there.
3. What I'd usually suggest is a type/subtype scheme. Create a table for "product" that contains a type code and the generic fields. Then for each of the true types -- books, toasters, cats, whatever -- create a separate table that is connected to the product table. Then when you need to do book-specific processing, process the book table. When you need to do generic processing, process the product table.

Comment: this aint a good idea .. you cannot enforce anything on such "mixed datatypes" ... (you cannot have INTEGER for ISBN while the toasters have alphanumeric ID) ... etc

Comment: @Mr.P I absolutely agree. I was trying to say that this is possible but generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

I understand this may not be the sort of answer you are looking for however unfortunately a relational database ( SQL ) is built upon the idea of a structured predefined schema. You are trying to store non structured schemaless data in a model that was not built for it. Yes you can fudge it so that you can technically store infinite amounts of meta data however this will soon cause lots of issues and quickly get out of hand. Just look at Wordpress and the amount of issues they have had with this approach and you can easily see why it is not a good idea.

Luckily this has been a long standing issue with relational databases which is why NoSQL schemaless databases that use a document approach were developed and have seen such a massive rise in popularity in the last decade. It's what all of the fortune 500 tech companies use to store ever changing user data as it allows for individual records to have as many or as little fields ( columns ) as they wish whilst remaining in the same collection ( table ).

Therefore I would suggest looking into NoSQL databases such as MongoDB and try to either convert over to them, or use them in conjunction with your relational database. Any types of data you know need to have the same amount of columns representing them should be stored in SQL and any types of data you know will differ between records should be stored in the NoSQL database.