# designing a product database

Tags: database-design

I need to setup a database for my product. I need to store product name, product prize, product detail, and product features in this database. One product has more than one feature now how can I setup this database?

I have setup a database with two tables

> 1. Product_detail  has id, p_name, p_detail, p_prize and
> 2. Product_ features has id,p_ features   (there are one more feathers for one database)

Is it correct? If correct so how can I make relation between a product and its features? And how can I retrieve the data from database?

If this is wrong so how can I make this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241033/designing-database-to-hold-different-metadata-information/3242426#3242426

Answer (score 1):

This is a common relational design pattern used to resolve many to many relationships like the one you describe. You need a link table to link `Product_detail` to `Product_features`.

I would rename your tables so you had `Product`, `Feature`, and the link table `ProductFeature`.

`ProductFeature` would consist of records containing product id and featureid (and probably more than one record per product.

So to retrieve all features for product with id 1

```
SELECT *
FROM product p
INNER JOIN productfeature pf ON pf.productid = p.id
INNER JOIN feature f ON pf.featureid = f.id
WHERE p.id = 1
```

You will need to add appropriate foreign keys, and you might consider encapsulating the query in a view (SQL Server construct, so not sure what the MySQL equivalent is)

Comment: Adding to embo's answer, keep in mind that similarly named product features don't always represent the same thing, so it's frequently useful to make thte latter product dependents - eg shirt size is not the same as pant size, and xs/s/m/l/xl is not necessarily 1/2/3/4/5.