# When to use columns and when a separate table? - Database Design

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

Most people don't recommend EAV and I know some of the reasons.
However what is the difference between an EAV-approach and such an approach?

Table **computer**:

```
id, price, description
```

Table **connections**:

```
id, name (possible values: LAN, USB, HDMI, ..., all all about 10)
```

Table **connections_computer**

```
comp_id, conn_id
```

Or is that EAV, too? If yes, what would be a normalized alternative?

Consider, that I want to do searches like that:

All computers, that have BOTH a LAN and a HDMI connection. In this case I would need 1 join / filter attribute, when having it as 1 column / attribute, searching would be easy, but I would have many NULL values.

Any recommendation how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is a plain many-to-many. In the **EAV** an *attribute name* is a **value** of a column, instead of being a **name** of the column. For example,

`computer: {computer_id, attr_name, attr_value}`

```
insert into computer (computer_id, attr_name, attr_value)
values
  (1, 'connection', 'HDMI')
, (1, 'connection', 'USB')
, (1, 'memory', '2 GB')
;
```

would be an EAV approach.

[**Here is an example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241033/designing-database-to-hold-different-metadata-information/3242426#3242426) of the price you pay for the EAV approach (flexibility) in a RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks, so I should use many-many and not 1 column / attribute value?

Comment: Yes, if you can design -- then design. Meaning that you know your entities and attributes. If you really have to use EAV -- have unknown entries/attributes which are to be defined by users on fly -- then consider document oriented DBs like Mongo, Couch etc..