# Designing tables for multiple product types

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema, entity-attribute-value

I have been looking to design a multiple product type database table. Assume for a moment I wish to add two different type products, a book and a computer software compact disc. These two product have a few distinct/unique attributes which relates to one but will absolutely make no sense to other.

Attribute for a book = ISBN, Pages, Author.

Software = preferred operating system, device it works on, no. of license.

Initially, I asked a similar question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718875/is-this-the-right-schema-for-an-e-commerce-application-which-may-want-to-sell-di), and was suggested that to scale I need to have a simple table with product_id and attribute_id
Working on the suggestion, and looking around for a bit of help, this is what I came up with.

[image]

Here we have a product table with a few common attributes that mostly may apply to all but a few column will take null, For the more product specific attributes, the user will need to create them on their own.

Can you please suggest if this is right?

Comment: How many columns in Product table have primary key defined ?

Comment: @BHouse, in product table the product_id is the primary key with auto increment and both product_description and product_attribute have product_id as a foreign key.

Comment: it is looking good, but i suggest you add a composite primary key for few other fields in Products like Supplier_id,Product_sku. Will prevent duplicate inserts

Comment: your question may have an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749525/relational-database-design-multiple-user-types/13752304#13752304

Comment: @WalterMitty, hey, thank you for the comment. I read your answer. You talked about "Class Table Inheritance". This is a continuity question to (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718875/is-this-the-right-schema-for-an-e-commerce-application-which-may-want-to-sell-di). I think the first diagram I put out was class-table inheritance, am new to this correct me if wrong, but was suggested otherwise. Can you please point out what is wrong with this particular design. Thank you again.

Comment: Research SQL/database subtyping questions/answers.

Comment: @Mecom "Can you please point out what is wrong with this particular design" Research also EAV pros/cons. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122656/database-design-for-multiple-product-types-with-variable-attributes (Please google many variants clear concise specific question statements/titles before you post.)

Comment: @philipxy, thank you for your response. I have gone through entity–attribute–value and understand the drawbacks. I posted this model (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718875/is-this-the-right-schema-for-an-e-commerce-application-which-may-want-to-sell-di) which was class table inheritance which was labeled unscalable. Is there a way of getting this database design (multiple product-type) right ever? What is the right way of designing a database which suitable for multiple product type?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your design, although I could easily not be seeing it.  I added my answer in case you were unaware of the terminology "Class Table Inheritance".  If you google on this term, I recommend the web pages by Fowler.  He seems to be able to communicate to both programmers and DBAs.