# Single Table Inheritance: Consequence of having too many null values in DB table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sti

I'm less than 1 years old in computing and I wish I took computer science in my early education years.

I'm developing in rails and thinking of applying STI. Number of columns in each subclasses are ranging from 5-6 and these are relatively same data type. And, I'm wondering having unique attributes for each subclasses is good idea.. or not?

What are the negative consequence of having too many null value in DB table?

- Does it degrade any computing performance?
- Does it affect search performance?

Since there are many shared data types in subclasses and not much difference in numbers of columns in each subclass, I can make same attribute names to reduce the total number of the columns for the table.

But, if I don't differentiate the attributes name in each subclasses, the input form for each subclass might be ugry in code. I don't want to put too much logics in view, and I can write better code in controller using AJAX.

What would you do?

Comment: Since you are asking about performance it might help to specify what DB are you using.
I would consider it a code smell, a sign that you need to split this table so your models represent the data more closely, so maybe those columns could be in another table and you simply would not have additional arrows if the data is null.

Comment: I find polymorphic associations are often a better fit than STI but since we don't know what tables/columns you're looking to setup I can't say for sure.

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba Thank you. I'm using PG. And yes, as you suggest, I'm thinking to create each of models for to represent each Product Details. I found a good article here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122656/database-design-for-multiple-product-types-with-variable-attributes Now I'm thinking how to apply it to rails.

Comment: @bkunzi01 Thank you. I'm trying to develop DB design that for Category, Products, and the Products Detail for each different category for E-Commerce. As you say polymorphic is better solution, I'm considering to have category_id on both Product and ProductDetail. But before that I want to understand this in rails way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122656/database-design-for-multiple-product-types-with-variable-attributes

Answer (score 0):

This case study from Reddit is really interesting, and I think this is the answer for why I should choose STI. http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/5/17/7-lessons-learned-while-building-reddit-to-270-million-page.html

> " Lesson 6: Store Redundant Data ... whose essential idea is: The key
>   to speed is to precompute everything and cache It."