# Database design to hold multiple item types

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys

I have a following problem of what the best approach to desining this part of the database is. Although not directly taken from the project, the example below should be good to illustrate what my issue is.

Let's say there's a website with unique/collector items to buy. The items are groupped into categories - each I've put in its own table. Let's take two as an example:

```
create table books (
  id bigint not null auto_increment primary key,
  -- common for all items
  username name(100) not null,
  description varchar(100)
  -- specific to books
  num_pages int,
  --[...]
  );

create table cds (
  id bigint not null auto_increment primary key,
  -- common for all items
  username name(100) not null,
  description varchar(100)
  -- specific to books
  num_songs int,
  --[...]
  );
```

In my own project each item type may have quite a few of its own properties, specific only to itself and irrelevant to other ones. There may also be quite a few item types.

This website allows to buy the items. For simplicity let's say that each entry in each item table is a single item (quantity 1) and each may only have one buyer.

Now, on to the problem - on that website I want to have a grand total list of all items bought, let's say in the last hour. The list displays the common fields (name, description, buyer) and allows to navigate to the item that has been bought to view its details in a separate page, which in turn displays fields specific to the category, plus the buyer if there's one.

My initial approach was this - I could create one table with the common columns + buyer_id + buy_date and have its PK as FK in each of the item type tables (books, cds etc.). That way I'd be able to easily display the global purchase history and while browsing the specific item I'd be able to see whether or not its been bought or not. The PK in that table could also be treated as sort of a "guid" for the items. However when browsing the history, how do I go back to a specific item in this case when they're all in multiple separate tables and all I have is this one table of guids? I could hold FK to each of those item PKs there, but that approach seems really strange and inefficient (only one FK would have to be set at a time). If there's 50 item types, that table would suddenly hold 50 different FKs with only one set each time. I could also hold a pair item_id+item_type and determine which table to query based on the item_type, but that also feels like something that could be solved in a better way.

How do I approach this? Maybe I could do something to the base assumptions that would make it a bit easier?

Comment: This is a faq, google my (endless} SO comments re subtyping. *Your current title* googles to answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database Design For Multiple Product Types with variable attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122656/database-design-for-multiple-product-types-with-variable-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have an Items table which enumerates items of all types. You buying transactions log would refer Items. Books, Cds and other type specific tables also would refer Items.

```
create table Items (
  id bigint not null auto_increment primary key,
  -- common for all items
  username name(100) not null,
  description varchar(100),
  -- type
  itemType nvarchar(128) NOT NULL
  );

create table books (
  id bigint not null foreign key refers Items(id),
  -- specific to books
  num_pages int,
  --[...]
  );
```