# Determine type from Class Table Inheritance

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, class-table-inheritance

I am trying to implement a database that has a table structure similar to below, where 2 tables are a subtype of a table.

An animal has a primary key, and dog and cat has a foreign key that references animal_id of animal.

```
animal(animal_id, bornAt)
dog(animal_id, barkSound)
cat(animal_id, meowSound)
```

It is worth noting that dog and cat are disjoint, so it is not possible for them to reference the same animal_id in animal.

Is there a way to use SQL code to determine the type of the animal, given the animal_id? For example, if there is a dog with animal_id of 4(not knowing the fact that animal_id 4 is dog), I would like to retrieve the data with a join from the animal and dog table.

Comment: What about two left joins, one on each subtype tables.

Comment: @Shadow Two left joins could work, as it would check the id for both subtypes. If I were to use that implementation, I will have to change the id for dog and cat, to be dog_id and cat_id, and check for the column that is not null.

Answer (score 5):

One way I have seen to enforce the disjoint types is to define an animal type column in the animal table, and make your foreign keys reference it.

```
animal(animal_id, animal_type, bornAt)
dog(animal_id, animal_type, barkSound)
cat(animal_id, animal_type, meowSound)
```

Suppose dog.animal_type is constrained to only 'dog', and cat.animal_type is constraint to only 'cat'. Then the foreign key from dog and cat referencing animal uses the *pair* of columns referencing a compound unique key in animal.

That way you get enforcement of your disjoint types, because a given row in animal must either have 'dog' or 'cat' but not both. Also you would know the animal type of a given row in the animal table without having to join to other tables to see if there's a match.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. For this implementation, I presume both animal_id and animal_type are required to determine the appropriate row and table of the animal.

Comment: Right, after you query a row from `animal` then you know which table to query for the animal-specific attributes.

Comment: this might be a more bulletproof answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17122961/1201238