# What are the Meta model design advantages and drawbacks with search engine (SOLR) usage?

Tags: java, database-design, solr, search-engine, metamodel

We are trying to model our database with a metamodel, for example:

1. [Link 1](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html)
2. [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241033/designing-database-to-hold-different-metadata-information#)

But we have limited foresight of this approach with a search engine. Therefore, we need your advice.

Basically, what problems that we will encounter with this metamodel approach when indexing, facet searching, and displaying query results?

I know I could not describe the limits or constraints for this question. But, I will answer regarding questions as best as I can.