# How can I create the database table for shopping website

Tags: mysql

I am little bit confused that how I have to create the tables for simple shopping website because I am new in php and this is my first project of shopping website choosen by myself for practice but I am confused with the size of the products and color of the products and different types of the products like laptops, mobile, jeans, shirts etc,

I have created the table but I want to know that two things

1. for electronics products I have to create a different table and for
2. clothes like jeans and shirts etc, I have to create a different table

   Please can anybody tell me the structure of the table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [designing database to hold different metadata information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241033/designing-database-to-hold-different-metadata-information)

Comment: create a table for products and just add a column for the different types. like `product_type: eletronics|shirts|etc`

Comment: You are jumping the gun, Start small, I suggest you start with small php applications, and get more practice more and more before jumping to databases.

Comment: @  Masivuye Cokile I have practice for 5 months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have many tables, for example:

```
Products:
    ID
    Name
    Description
    Etc...

Categories:
    ID
    Name

ProductCategories:
    ProductID
    CategoryID

Types:
    ID
    Name

ProductTypes:
    ProductID
    TypeID
```

This enables you to have products in multiple categories and of multiple types...

Added further examples as per the comment below. For sizes you have a Sizes table, and a mapping table to map products to sizes...

```
Sizes:
    ID
    Name

ProductSizes:
    ProductID
    SizeID
```

If you also need to consider colours, and need to make a choice whether you will store sizes that have a colour, or colours that have a size...

```
Colours:
    ID
    Name

ProductColours
    ProductID
    ColourID
```

Or, if you need colours and sizes, or any further complexity, i would abstract it right out and use a `ProductAttributes` way of doing it, maybe out of the scope of this question as the answer would be quite lengthy indeed.

But in the same style as above, you could have a table like so:

```
ProductSizesColours:
    ProductID
    SizeID
    ColourID
```

Which enables you to store data for products such as:

A pair of jeans that are size 32 and colour brown.
A juice blenderthat is 3 litre size and colour white.
Etc...

Comment: But if a product of a brand like levis shirt have the same model but different size and different colours how can i manage this in database

Comment: I want to know one thing that if a user chooses a size and color  of a shoes and that is not in the database show what would be the sql query about it I am confused

Comment: Your users will not be able to choose a size/colour combination that does not exist, because you will only be presenting the options that /do/ exist

Answer (score 0):

I think you sould create a new table like "type_product" to add the type of each product and put all your product in the same table